# Python PySerial changing settings on timeout

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a question about Python and PySerial.
On my Raspberry Pi i want to read a serial port from a device. I got 2 types of devices i want to read from. They both got different settings:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=0
ser.rtscts=0
ser.timeout=20
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0
```

and:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=1
ser.rtscts=0
ser.timeout=20
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0
```

This is the code to read the serial port:

```
try:
    ser.open()
except:
    sys.exit ("Error opening %s."  % ser.name)

t_count = 0

while t_count < 20:
    t_line = ''

    try:
        t_raw = ser.readline()
    except serial.SerialException:
        sys.exit ("Serial port %s could not be read." % ser.name )

    t_str = str(t_raw)
    t_line = t_str.strip()
    print (t_line)
    t_count += 1

try:
    ser.close()
except:
    sys.exit ("Oops %s. Program aborted. Could not close serial port." % ser.name )
```

So when i connect to a device with 115200 but the device runs 9600, i get timeouts ofcourse. But in my program it will just time out twenty times (times the for loop will run), and no exception to be thrown. Not even just before the program exits after looping 20 times. No error message nothing.

What i want to achieve is the following, i want to make the python script self detecting what he is connected to. When the readline() times out 20 times it should change settings. (by running another function or something).
I cant check if the readline returns something empty, because there are empty lines in the serial message.

Is there any way to get the right exception? Or any other smart way to solve this?

(By the way, i am sure the settings work. As i tested them both and run fine.)

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try xonoff=0 with 152000 baud rate ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to create a handshake function,
send something with one serial handler that you know the device will respond to correctly. If the answer is jibberish  then change the handler and try the other one until you succceed.